# File to Array in Lua

Tags: file, io, lua

I was wondering how do I get a line into an array with lua in some sort of function

eg. FileToArray("C:/file.txt")?

I know I can use: 
var = io.open("file")
Data = var:read()
But it only returns  the 1st line, and no other lines.

Anyone know how to fix this or a different way? I'm new to lua and the file system stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass `"*a"` to read function, it should read the whole file:

```
local file = io.open("file-name", "r");
local data = file:read("*a")
```

And if you want to store each line in an array. Like Jane's solution you can use
io:lines () - which returns iterator function (each call  gives you a new line)

```
 local file = io.open("file-name", "r");
 local arr = {}
 for line in file:lines() do
    table.insert (arr, line);
 end
```

Comment: note that it's only "*a" the fact the "*all" works is chance: it only looks at the first 2 characters.

Comment: [You are absolutely right](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file:read) , I don't know why I wrote '*all'

Comment: even better than using :lines is io.lines("path"). It will close the file in the last iteration.

Comment: What is the "rb" in the format for? I know "r" is read mode, but "rb"?

Comment: It's supposed to be binary mode, it is not necessary. I think lua must have ignore it.

Comment: Really quick, is there a way to set the "path" I've seen it but I've forgotten what it was.

Comment: Like instead of "C:/folder/file.txt" you can just do "file.txt"

Comment: I do not think you can do that, you can modify `package.path` but that only works with `loadfile` and `require` and is used for loading lua modules and lua files not for arbitrary files. You can use relative path in regard to the script's current directory of course.

Comment: I up-voted this answer, but would like to recommend this [unofficial Lua FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T2.3) site as there are other goodies.  Note, I have no affiliate with this site whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

```
local file = io.open("c:\\file.txt")
local tbllines = {}
local i = 0
if file then
    for line in file:lines() do
     i = i + 1
     tbllines[i] = line
    end
    file:close()
else
    error('file not found')
end
```

See: http://lua-users.org/wiki/IoLibraryTutorial for more information.